# Image path problem when executing Python multiprocessing

Tags: python

### There is no problem without multiprocessing.
Using multiprocessing alone causes path problems.
No matter how hard I search, I can't find the answer to the content, so I ask for help

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
from keras.preprocessing.image import array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool


def b(path):
    for f in path:   
        print (f)     
        new_img = load_img(f,target_size=(256,256)) 
        arr_img = img_to_array(new_img)
    return arr_img


def main():
    start = int(time.time())
    num_cores = 4
    pool = Pool(num_cores)
    pool.map(b, 'C:\\Users\\003.png')
    print("***run time(sec) :", int(time.time()) - start)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

Error message

```
load_img
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C'
```

---

The error message is the same even if it is put as a variable as follows.

```
def main():
    start = int(time.time())
    num_cores = 4
    pool = Pool(num_cores)
    bb = 'C:\\Users\\003.png'
    pool.map(b, bb)
    print("***run time(sec) :", int(time.time()) - start)
```

Answer (score 0):

this piece of code has the problem.
`pool.map(b, 'C:\\Users\\003.png')`

you are using map, the first parameter is a function(which is okay for you), and the second need to be iterable, so it need to be like(a list for example) `['C:\\Users\\003.png']`

because you gave it like `'C:\\Users\\003.png'` map is trying to iterate it like C , then :\ and so on. which is throwing the error. so please change your code to (i.e a list)

`pool.map(b, ['C:\\Users\\003.png'])`